# jsf navigates to same page again and again

Tags: java, jsf-1.2

My view:

```
<h:commandLink  action="#{Test.action}" target="_self">test</h:commandLink>  
<h:commandLink  action="#{Test1.action}" target="_self">test1</h:commandLink>
```

My classes:

```java
class Test
{
    // ...

    public String action()
    {
        return "outcome-1";
    }
}

class Test1
{
    // ...

    public String action()
    {
        return "outcome-2";
    }
}
```

**step 1:** Navigate from  `1.jsp` to `2.jsp`

> 18:36:14,371 INFO  [STDOUT] START PHASE UPDATE_MODEL_VALUES 4
>   18:36:14,371 INFO  [STDOUT] /pages/1.jsp
>   18:36:14,371 INFO  [STDOUT] END PHASE UPDATE_MODEL_VALUES 4
>   18:36:14,371 INFO  [STDOUT] /pages/1.jsp
>   18:36:14,371 INFO  [STDOUT] START PHASE INVOKE_APPLICATION 5
>   18:36:14,371 INFO  [STDOUT] /pages/1.jsp
>   18:36:14,371 INFO  [STDOUT] END PHASE INVOKE_APPLICATION 5
>   18:36:14,371 INFO  [STDOUT] /pages/2.jsp
>   18:36:14,371 INFO  [STDOUT] START PHASE RENDER_RESPONSE 6
>   18:36:14,371 INFO  [STDOUT] /pages/2.jsp
>   18:36:14,464 INFO  [STDOUT] END PHASE RENDER_RESPONSE 6
>   18:36:14,464 INFO  [STDOUT] /pages/2.jsp

**step 2:** Navigate from  `2.jsp` to `3.jsp`

> 18:36:55,368 INFO  [STDOUT] START PHASE UPDATE_MODEL_VALUES 4
>   18:36:55,368 INFO  [STDOUT] /pages/2.jsp
>   18:36:55,368 INFO  [STDOUT] END PHASE UPDATE_MODEL_VALUES 4
>   18:36:55,368 INFO  [STDOUT] /pages/2.jsp
>   18:36:55,368 INFO  [STDOUT] START PHASE INVOKE_APPLICATION 5
>   18:36:55,368 INFO  [STDOUT] /pages/2.jsp
>   18:36:55,368 INFO  [STDOUT] END PHASE INVOKE_APPLICATION 5
>   18:36:55,368 INFO  [STDOUT] /pages/3.jsp
>   18:36:55,368 INFO  [STDOUT] START PHASE RENDER_RESPONSE 6
>   18:36:55,368 INFO  [STDOUT] /pages/3.jsp
>   18:36:56,164 INFO  [STDOUT] END PHASE RENDER_RESPONSE 6
>   18:36:56,164 INFO  [STDOUT] /pages/3.jsp

**step 3:** Navigate from `3.jsp` to `2.jsp`

> 18:39:09,575 INFO  [STDOUT] END PHASE UPDATE_MODEL_VALUES 4
>   18:39:09,575 INFO  [STDOUT] /pages/3.jsp
>   18:39:09,575 INFO  [STDOUT] START PHASE INVOKE_APPLICATION 5
>   18:39:09,575 INFO  [STDOUT] /pages/3.jsp
>   18:39:09,575 INFO  [STDOUT] END PHASE INVOKE_APPLICATION 5
>   18:39:09,575 INFO  [STDOUT] /pages/3.jsp
>   18:39:09,575 INFO  [STDOUT] START PHASE RENDER_RESPONSE 6
>   18:39:09,575 INFO  [STDOUT] /pages/3.jsp
>   18:39:09,716 INFO  [STDOUT] END PHASE RENDER_RESPONSE 6
>   18:39:09,716 INFO  [STDOUT] /pages/3.jsp

In step 3, Navigating from `3.jsp` to `2.jsp` renders `3.jsp` itself but same navigation works in above step 1 & 2.

Comment: Can you provide your `faces-config.xml`?

Comment: <navigation-rule>
   
 <navigation-case>
   <from-outcome>outcome-1</from-outcome>
   <to-view-id>/pages/1.jsp</to-view-id>
   
  </navigation-case>
  <navigation-case>
   <from-outcome>outcome-2</from-outcome>
   <to-view-id>/pages/2.jsp</to-view-id>
   
  </navigation-case>
  
  <navigation-case>
   <from-outcome>outcome-3</from-outcome>
   <to-view-id>/pages/3.jsp</to-view-id>
   
  </navigation-case>
  
  
</navigation-rule>

Comment: @Sal:     `<navigation-rule> <navigation-case> <from-outcome>outcome-1</from-outcome> <to-view-id>/pages/1.jsp</to-view-id> </navigation-case> <navigation-case> <from-outcome>outcome-2</from-outcome> <to-view-id>/pages/2.jsp</to-view-id> </navigation-case> <navigation-case> <from-outcome>outcome-3</from-outcome> <to-view-id>/pages/3.jsp</to-view-id> </navigation-case> </navigation-rule>`

Comment: Thanks, BTW you can edit your post and put the navigation rules there and use code formatting

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure your navigation cases in faces-config.xml.
For example, if you want to navigate from 1.jsp to 2.jsp, you must configure your navigation rule:

```
<navigation-rule>
    <from-view-id>/1.jsp</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>outcome-2</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/2.jsp</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```

Comment: I can goto 1.jsp, 2.jsp, 3.jsp from a menu of 11.jsp,12.jsp [rich faces panel menu item rendered inside <t:panelGrid>]etc... unfortunately the last rendered view alone retains. I have to do logout in my application.

Comment: Are you working with ajax rendering? If so, render a parent panelGroup or panelGrid, so the pages appears to you.

Comment: I am not using ajax for rendering.